# QoS in serviced offices

Tags: internet, qos, connection-sharing

We recently have encountered a problem on our two shared lines provided by Regus in a serviced office.

When there is download on either connection it renders the Internet unusable for anyone. I've noticed this on typical shared connections, though I'm surprised to see it now on two separate lines.

Can someone offer an explanation, advice or solution for providing a more stable connection whilst a download or upload for that matter is in progress?

Comment: I'm trying out http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service [HTB - Hierarchical Token Bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket#Hierarchical_token_bucket) with 1500 kpbs since we are limited to a symmetrical 2Meg cap. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to enable fair queueing (or weighted fair queueing), that usually makes it better for the lower-bandwidth connections, with a slight impact for teh "bulk" usage.

Don't know how to do that on other than Cisco routers (that being what I mostly work with), but on those, the thing to look for is "fair-queue" or "no fair-queue" in the interface configuration (or either "fifo" or "weighted fair" on the "Queueing strategy" in the output from `show interface`).